# Submit button not working using jQuery validation in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ruby2 and rails4. I have the validation using jQuery. The validation errors are shown correctly, but when I click on submit button it does nothing though I had given the correct value for field. Can anybody please help me to solve the problem? My code is shown below. Thank you.

jQuery plugin:

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js
 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js
```

In download.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag file_download_contacts_path, :method => :post, :id => 'contact-form'  do |f| %>         
  <h3><b>Download Form</b></h3>      
  <div>   

  <div><%=  label_tag :Name  %><br />  
    <%= text_field_tag "contact[name]" , nil, placeholder: "Your Name" %></div>         
<div><%=  label_tag :Email %><br />
    <%= email_field_tag "contact[email]" , nil, placeholder: "your@mail.com" %></div>
<div><%=  label_tag :Mobile %><br />
    <%= telephone_field_tag "contact[phone]" , nil, placeholder: "Your Contact No" %></div>
<div><br/><%= button_tag 'submit' %></div>
  </div>    
 <% end %>              


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#contact-form").validate({
debug: true,
rules: {
"contact[name]": {required: true, max: false, min: false},  
"contact[email]": {required: true, email: true},        
"contact[phone]": {required: true, digits: true, minlength: 10, maxlength: 10}                
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From jQuery Validation Plugin documentation

> debug (default: false)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Enables debug mode. If true, the form is not submitted and certain errors are displayed on the console

Just remove the line  `debug: true`  form your validation method and you'll be okay.

Comment: I am having 3 different pages on same sign-up form, I want to keep validating on 'Next' button(used to go to next page). But if I remove `debug: true`, then it will not work, because form is getting submitted on 'Next' button.